# How `yes|head` works?

Tags: bash, shell, signals, pipeline

As per this [post](http://linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php), which says that

> The kernel sends SIGPIPE to any process which tries to write to a pipe with no readers. This is useful, because otherwise jobs like `yes | head` would never terminate.

If I understand it correctly, when `yes|head` is invoked by the user,

1. `yes` and `head` would be running in parallel at first
2. later, `head` stops running
3. `yes` would receive a SIGPIPE signal when it tries to write to the pipe

Am I right? If I miss something, please let me know.

Comment: Those are the essentials. If you're on Linux, you can see it in detail by using `strace`. (`strace yes | head` to see the `yes` side, and `yes | strace head` to see the `head` side.) Note that `yes` writes a full buffer's worth of data to the pipe, and `head` doesn't read it all. So a lot of it is dropped on the floor. That's easier to see with `seq` than with `yes`.

Comment: @rici Thank you for pointing out that. One more question arises, I can see ` SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=52597, si_uid=900026776} +++ killed by SIGPIPE +++` in the output of `strace yes | head`. And there is such output when invoking `strace seq 1 1900 | head`, whereas it could not be seen in the output of `strace seq 1 12 | head`. It seems that `seq 1 12` exits before `head`.

Comment: yes, that's correct. As I said, the producer writes complete buffers of data, each such write (to a pipe) is an atomic operation. So the first buffer will succeed. Buffers are several thousand characters, and `seq 1 12`'s output comfortably fits in a single buffer.

Comment: `man setvbuf` has some basic information about C library buffering, but any good C textbook should provide it as well, possibly in a more digestible form. The bottom-line is that pipes are not terminals, so the producer's stdout defaults to "fully-buffered". You can play around with the command `stdbuf` to see the impact.

Comment: @rici Thank you for the tips. I posted some questions about `stdbuf` & `setvbuf` several days ago. I don't see any difference when invoking `strace stdbuf -o0 seq 1 12 | head `, which makes the corresponding stream be unbuffered on purpose, here is the [output](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0f545617b028f46). No `killed by SIGPIPE` is seen, either. But `strace stdbuf -oL seq 1 12 | head` works very differently. I could see the aforementioned message [in the output](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf61dd1fb7e346a4)!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of it in action:

```
% yes | uniq &
[1] 71546
y
% ps gxa | grep yes
  71545 pts/0    S      0:05 yes
% kill -PIPE 71545
%
[1]+  Done                    yes | uniq
```

Call `yes` piped to `uniq` in a subshell. You see the lone "y" printed and the job back-grounded. Wait a bit then find the PID of the `yes` process still running. Then send the PIPE signal to it. Everything completes cleanly.

Looking at the [source for yes](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/tree/master/src), we find no handler for SIGPIPE. So the default action of terminate is used.